# Why is one not allowed to use a Boolean in a docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker-compose

Defining a boolean in a docker-compose.yml file:

```
environment:
  SOME_VAR: true
```

and running `docker up` results in:

```
contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null
```

**Attempts to solve the issue**

1. If true is changed to True the issue persists.
2. Using `'true'` is not accepted by the code itself ([a play framework app](https://www.playframework.com/) is started using the `./target/universal/stage/bin/APPNAME -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=`, i.e. either `-Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true` or `-Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=false` parameter):

   VAR has type STRING rather than BOOLEAN
3. Using `yes` or `no` as a variable results in:

   contains true, which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null
4. Using `yes` and using a script that transforms `yes` to true works

**Discussion**

[According the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#entrypoint) `Any boolean values; true, false, yes no, need to be enclosed in quotes to ensure they are not converted to True or False by the YML parser`:

> **Environment**
>
> Add environment variables. You can use either an array or a
>   dictionary. Any boolean values; true, false, yes no, need to be
>   enclosed in quotes to ensure they are not converted to True or False
>   by the YML parser.
>
> Environment variables with only a key are resolved to their values on
>   the machine Compose is running on, which can be helpful for secret or
>   host-specific values.
>
> ```
> environment:
>   RACK_ENV: development
>   SHOW: 'true'
>   SESSION_SECRET:
>
> environment:
>   - RACK_ENV=development
>   - SHOW=true
>   - SESSION_SECRET
> ```

**Question**

Why is it not allowed?

Comment: Not about DevOps? `DevOps Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software engineers working on automated testing, continuous delivery, service integration and monitoring, and building SDLC infrastructure`

Comment: @Aurora0001 question updated

Comment: try `SOME_VAR: "true"` or `SOME_VAR: 1` if this works for you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This come from a design choice of YAML language about [booleans](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html)

Every unquoted value matching this "regex":

```
 y|Y|yes|Yes|YES|n|N|no|No|NO
|true|True|TRUE|false|False|FALSE
|on|On|ON|off|Off|OFF
```

Will be converted to `True`  or `False`. Note that from [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10212-boolean) and onwards it appears that only `true` and `false` will be interpreted as boolean values.

This start causing a problem when your code will test an environment value to be yes or no for example taking this script (other examples [in the PR discution](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2000#issuecomment-138676720)):

```
if [ "$SOME_VAR" == "yes" ];
then
  echo "Variable SOME_VAR is activated"
else
  echo "Variable SOME_VAR is NOT activated"
fi
```

And setting in your compose file

```
environment:
  SOME_VAR: yes
```

Will result in `SOME_VAR` being `True` when the script run, hence taking the wrong case as it is not equal to `yes`.

So the choice [has been made](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1788) to [disallow boolean](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/2000) to prevent unwanted behaviors hard to debug when you're not aware of the YAML rule.

I see two way to get over the problem:

1. Using an [`env_file`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/#envfile) instead, they are not parsed IIRC and should prevent the conversion.
2. As you already said, use a wrapper script around your launcher to define the value instead before launching the app, something along the line of this should do:

   ```
    AUTOAPPLY=false
    if [ "$SOME_VAR" == "true" ]
    then
        AUTOAPPLY=true
    fi

    ./target/universal/stage/bin/APPNAME -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=$AUTOAPPLY
   ```

Comment: change yaml 1.2.2 boolean only (true|false) https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#10212-boolean

Comment: There's already a note about that in the answer

Answer (score 11):

That's YAML. It interprets `true` as a boolean. Envars must be strings, hence the requirement to make the type explicit via quotes.

Test this out with https://www.json2yaml.com/

Comment: More generally, the quotes won't appear in the value itself because they are YAML formatting.

Answer (score 4):

double quotes worked for me. Example:

```
environment:
  MY_VAR: "true"
```